# difference between node.run_state vs global varibale in a ruby file chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

would like to know the difference and recommended approach to use between global variable vs node.run_state

**test.rb**

```
dbpassword=''


ruby_block "load_databag_secret" do
  block do
    secret_key = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/home/test/db_key")
        db_keys = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("mydatabag", "mydatabagitem", secret_key) 
    end
    dbpassword=db_keys['DB_PASSWORD']
node.run_state['password']=db_keys['DB_PASSWORD']
      end
    end

execute "Enable on hosts" do

  command lazy { "echo #{node.run_state['password']} > /home/app/db.txt" }
end

    template "/config/properties" do
            source "properties.erb"
            variables(lazy {
                         :db_password => { node.run_state['password'] },

                      })
```

or using node.run_state['password'] in place of global variable in this .rb file

Now execute command worked fine im able to see the password on the echoed file db.txt where as when i used lazy in template variables it outputed as empty value for db_password in template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a few issues, first what you have there isn't a global variable, it's a local variable. Globals in Ruby start with `$`. Second, you can't assign to a local variable from an enclosing scope like that in Ruby (or, indeed, in most languages). That assignment just creates a second `dbpassword` local variable scoped to the block. You could, however, use a mutation rather than a variable assignment (e.g. `dbpassword << whatever`). Third, you can't actually use `lazy` deeply inside the variables hash like that, it has to be at the top level. Fourth, you can straight up side-step all of this if you're only using the value you once like in that example:

```
template "/config/properties" do
  source "properties.erb"
  variables lazy { 
    secret_key = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/home/test/db_key")
    db_keys = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("mydatabag", "mydatabagitem", secret_key)
    {db_password: db_keys['DB_PASSWORD']}
  }
end
```

Just for completeness in case others find this via Google, with real global variables the biggest difference is unit testing, the run state is tied to the converge so individual unit tests won't see each other's values which is always nice (though of course you could work around this in your code).

Comment: im positive to use node.runstate..but can you please lemme know how can i use that node.runstate outside rubyblock i mean not in templates though..updated my question

Comment: The execute resource is for running external commands so I'm not even sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Sure, if using the value twice like that, storing it in the run state is more reasonable, if a bit ugly :)

Comment: no it didnt work on template varibale it ouputs as empty value for db_password in properties.erb template instead of node.runstate value